# Are ASP and ASP.NET entirely separate in IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, asp

This is probably a silly question, but the names are confusing and I can't find a direct answer. There are a lot of [limits in the ASP section](http://i2.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp/limits) of the IIS configuration that I might want to tweak (such as bufferingLimit, maxRequestEntityAllowed, and queueTimeout) -- but only if they affect ASP.NET.

But I suspect that they don't. Is this correct? Are ASP and ASP.NET entirely different entities as far as IIS 7.5 is concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP and ASP.NET settings are treated as separate entities.  ASP is considered "Classic ASP" and is more of a server-side scripting method -JScript/VBScript-. ASP.NET relies on the .NET Framework -it is compiled-, and ASP.NET applications run in their own AppPool's.

The answer would be "yes."

Answer (score 2):

Yup, entirely different. Something applying to system.webServer/asp will not affect system.web or system/webServer (any other section) settings in the slightest.